# how to split marking in spotfire cross table with multiple-calculation custom expressions?

Tags: spotfire

Working in a cross table in Spotfire I've got (column names) on the horizontal (columns) axis and a custom expression for cell values:

```
Count(If(Year([milestone_date])=Year(DateTimeNow()),True)) as [YTD], 
Count() as [Total]
```

The calculations are working fine but the problem is the marking. I'd like to create a details visualization enabling users to see the underlying records in either "YTD" or "Total" columns, but as written, clicking on either YTD or Total values ends up marking both cells and pushing all underlying records to the details visualization. I don't think I can handle this through the horizontal (columns) axis as the records needed for the [YTD] and [Total] calculations are overlapping (i.e. not mutually exclusive)

Any ideas how to enable marking one but not the other?
[screencap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZgu5.png)